# How do I use the getblocktemplate RPC command of Bitcoin Core GUI? I tried the following usages but none of them worked

Tags: json-rpc, rpc-error-4

I tried the following commands, but none of them worked.

```
-getblocktemplate "segwit"
-Error: Error parsing JSON: segwit

-getblocktemplate ("segwit")
-Error: Error parsing JSON: segwit

-getblocktemplate "rules": ["segwit"]
-Error: Error parsing JSON: rules:

-getblocktemplate {"rules": ["segwit"]}
-Error: Error parsing JSON: {rules:

-getblocktemplate
-getblocktemplate must be called with the segwit rule set (call with {"rules": ["segwit"]}) (code -8)

-getblocktemplate {"rules": ["segwit"]}
-Error: Error parsing JSON: {rules:
```

How can I use this command correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GUI's debug console operates similarly to a shell. It needs quotes around the entire JSON string so that it is first interpreted as a string before the JSON is parsed. Then, if you used double quotes, you need to escape the quotes that are part of the JSON so that they aren't misinterpreted.

A valid way of writing this command is

```
getblocktemplate "{\"rules\":[\"segwit\"]}"
```

Alternatively, to avoid additional escaping, you can use single quotes on the outside:

```
getblocktemplate '{"rules":["segwit"]}'
```